# Fetch balances from Binance using NextJS, ccxt and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js, binance, ccxt

I'm trying to fetch balances from Binance in my NextJS 13 application, which uses the `/src/app` dir and TypeScript.

```
async function getData() {   
  const exchange = new ccxt.binance ({
    "apiKey": "mykey",
    "secret": "mysecret",
  })
  return exchange.fetchTotalBalance()
}
 
export default async function Page() {
  const data = await getData()
  return <main>{data. Total}</main>
}
```

But I keep getting an error:

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\myapp\.next\server\static_dependencies\node-fetch\index.js' imported from D:\myapp\.next\server\app\page.js

Tried to install and import node-fetch package,didn't help.
Unfortunately, there is little information about ccxt usage with React/NextJS. So, help is needed.

Comment: It looks like the problem only with the new /app router, using old /pages working as expected. Created a bug in the NextJS official GitHub, will post a solution here when get it ot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on NextJS GitHub, and @bludnic gave this solution, which I tried and seems to be working:

Solved by replacing fetch implementation of CCXT with the NextJS fetch.

```
import ccxt from 'ccxt'

const fetcher = (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => fetch(...args);

export default async function Page() {
  const exchange = new ccxt.binance()
  exchange.fetchImplementation = fetcher // <-

  const price = await exchange.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT')

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(price)}</div>
}
```

The discussion is here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/53200